# Serial column of datatype text in psql

Tags: postgresql

I am having a two-column table trial(id serial, value text).

Then I use `ALTER TABLE` to change the data type of `id` to `text`, and still if I insert records like:

```
insert into trial(value) values('name');
```

Then serial is still getting incremented everytime I am adding rows into it. If I insert a row like

```
insert into trial values(111111111111....a very large number, 'name');
```

It still works and it still increments the serial counter.

My question is:
why doesn't it overflow? Though the datatype of the column is text, the serial value would be still stored in a integer internally right? what is the data type of the variable that holds the serial value of a table(in psql's implementation) so that I can be sure that it would never overflow?

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: create table trial( id serial, value text);

Comment: Then you cannot store `id`s over 2147483647.

Comment: but explicitly providing a large id works

Comment: I don't believe that, if you really used `serial`.

Comment: Sir I have added a link to the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yEvPqK32DapJzRsReIcRUa_RsmC0WPUg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Aha. You didn't mention the `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: cast is different from alter table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert an explicit value into a column with a `DEFAULT`, the default value is not used. It does not matter that the value you enter is not a valid `integer` - it is a valid `text`, that is all that matters.

If you don't enter a value for `id`, PostgreSQL uses the sequence and converts the result to `text`.

Comment: Will 2147483647 be the max value of the sequence?

Comment: Depends on how it is defined (`\ds+ triall_id_seq`).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much sir for investing so much of your precious time into my question.